# How to get only last two values(Helloworld - test0 - test!) in oracle using function "regexp_substr"?

Tags: oracle10g

From the below query, I want to display the substring "test0 -test!" after the string is splitted by the delimeter "-".
select regexp_substr('Helloworld - test0 - test!' ,'[^ - ]+',1,1)from dual;

Could you  please help me on this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could expand the pattern to:

```
select regexp_substr('Helloworld - test0 - test!' ,'[^ -]+ - [^ -]+$', 1, 1)
from dual;

REGEXP_SUBSTR
-------------
test0 - test!
```

... which treats any run of spaces and dashes the same, as your original pattern did (because it's in square brackets).

You could also use `regexp_replace()` with back references (this can probably be simplified!):

```
select regexp_replace('Helloworld - test0 - test!' ,'(.*)( - )(.*)( - )(.*)$', '\3\4\5')
from dual;

REGEXP_REPLAC
-------------
test0 - test!
```

But you don't need regular expressions, as long as you know there are at least two `-` separators you can use `substr()` with `instr()`:

```
select substr('Helloworld - test0 - test!',
  instr('Helloworld - test0 - test!', ' - ', -1, 2) + 3)
from dual;

SUBSTR('HELLO
-------------
test0 - test!
```

The `instr()` counts backwards from the end of the string (because of the `-1` as the third argument), and finds the second appearance counting backwards, which puts you at the space immediately after the `d`. You then add three to step back over the delimiter, to find the start of the bit you want.

---

If you actually want to skip the first token (as you suggested in a comment), rather than always get the last two tokens (as the question says), then it's even easier:

```
select substr('Helloworld - test0 - test!',
  instr('Helloworld - test0 - test!', ' - ', 1, 1) + 3)
from dual;

SUBSTR('HELLO
-------------
test0 - test!
```

or with your second string:

```
select substr('welcome - to - stackoverflow - test!',
  instr('welcome - to - stackoverflow - test', ' - ', 1, 1) + 3)
from dual;

SUBSTR('WELCOME-TO-STACKOV
--------------------------
to - stackoverflow - test!
```

You can still use `regexp_replace()` if you prefer, though it's usually more expensive:

```
select regexp_replace('Helloworld - test0 - test!', '^[^ -]+ - ', null, 1, 1)
from dual;

REGEXP_REPLAC
-------------
test0 - test!

select regexp_replace('welcome - to - stackoverflow - test!', '^[^ -]+ - ', null, 1, 1)
from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('WELCOME-TO
--------------------------
to - stackoverflow - test!
```

---

If you want to split just on a dash, not space-dash-space, then that's simpler again. but if you also want to remove any leading spaces that leaves behind you'll need to add a trim to get rid of that:

```
ltrim(substr(your_string, instr(your_string, '-', 1, 1) + 1))
```

or:

```
ltrim(regexp_replace(your_string ,'^[^-]+-', null, 1, 1))
```

or remove it as part of the pattern:

```
regexp_replace(your_string ,'^[^- ]+ ?- ?', null, 1, 1)
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex!   I have one more questions.I do not want to consider first word after the splitted the string.so,Can I use the query to not consider first word and please let me know if there is any query?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean. You said you wanted the last two delimited elements. These all seem to produce the output you said you wanted.

Comment: My requirement is,I need to display all the words with delimeter "-" after the first delimeter "-". For example, welcome - to - stackoverflow -test, Always I will not consider the word welcome and want to display to -stackoverflow -test dynamically

Comment: It helps if your question describes what you actually want - 'get only last two values' in the title is rather misleading. Anyway, I've added how to do that.

Comment: Hello Alex,                                                                                            
 select regexp_replace('welcome-to -stackoverflow-test!', '^[^ -]+ - ', null, 1, 1)
from dual; the query is not working with the String "welcome-to -stackoverflow-test" .the string without space in between the character"-".Could you please help me on this?

Comment: @user3282682 - I've added a variation that will work for that string, and will also give the same result for the earlier ones - I've assumed you don;t want to keep any trailing spaces between the first dash and the remaining tokens.